# Разбиение строки с помощью регулярных выражений (Python)

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка:

```
4 spami42e3 nani3e
```

Мне надо её разбить так, чтобы получилось

```
 spam 42 nan 3(между элементами-пробел)
```

Конечно, вместо `spam`, `nan` и т. д. Могут стоять другие слова, большей или меньшей длины. Кол-во слов может быть больше или меньше. То же касается и чисел. Т. е.:

```
10 mmmmmmasdwi432123432390e30 mamamsdsdlfokcmvndksolmcsqwerli40e
```

Я думаю, нужно разбить строку по любому числу и пробелу после него. Затем разбить то ,что осталось по `i`<любое число>`e`, при этом число не трогать (перед ним поставить пробел). 
Как это сделать с использованием рег. выражений?

```
#Открыл файл с содержанием -       l4:spami42ee
#                                  l3:nani3ee

with open ('b.txt', 'r') as file:
    A=[]
    A=file.readlines() #Считал все строки в список
    l = [line.rstrip() for line in A] # Удалил \n   
    for i in range(len(l)):
        l[i]=l[i][1:len(l[i])-1]# Сделал срез, чтобы в начале убрать l, 
                                #в конце e
    a=''
    for i in range(len(l)):
        a+=l[i]                  #конкатенация
    a=a.replace(':',' ')         #замена
'''Добился spami42enani3e, как разбить вот эту строку, по i<любое число>e. 
При этом i и e удалить, а число между ними оставить(перед числом пробел)
'''
Q=a.split(' ')
    for i in range(len(Q)):
        if (Q[i].startswith('0') or Q[i].startswith('2') or
            Q[i].startswith('3') or Q[i].startswith('4') or
            Q[i].startswith('5') or Q[i].startswith('6') or
            Q[i].startswith('7') or Q[i].startswith('8') or
            Q[i].startswith('9')):
            Q[i]=Q[i][1:len(Q[i])]
        if (Q[i].endswith('0') or Q[i].endswith('2') or
            Q[i].endswith('3') or Q[i].endswith('4') or
            Q[i].endswith('5') or Q[i].endswith('6') or
            Q[i].endswith('7') or Q[i].endswith('8') or
            Q[i].endswith('9')):
            Q[i]=Q[i][0:len(Q[i])-1]
    D=''
    for i in range(len(Q)):
        D+=Q[i]

'''Спасибо,получилось'''
pattern = re.compile(r"(?<=\d)(?=[a-zA-Z])|(?=\d)(?<=[a-zA-Z])")
result = re.sub(pattern, " ", D)
print('Стало',result)
W=result.split(' ')
for i in range(len(W)):
    if W[i].endswith('i'):
        W[i]=W[i][0:len(W[i])-1]
print(W)
for i in range(len(W)):
    if W[i].startswith('e'):
        W[i]=W[i][1:len(W[i])]
print(W)
'''ИТОГ'''
with open ('b.txt', 'r') as file:
A=[]
A=file.readlines()
l = [line.rstrip() for line in A]
for i in range(len(l)):
    l[i]=l[i][1:len(l[i])-1]
a=''
for i in range(len(l)):
    a+=l[i]
a=a.replace(':',' ')
Q=a.split(' ')
for i in range(len(Q)):
    if (Q[i].startswith('0') or Q[i].startswith('2') or
        Q[i].startswith('3') or Q[i].startswith('4') or
        Q[i].startswith('5') or Q[i].startswith('6') or
        Q[i].startswith('7') or Q[i].startswith('8') or
        Q[i].startswith('9')):
        Q[i]=Q[i][1:len(Q[i])]
    if (Q[i].endswith('0') or Q[i].endswith('2') or
        Q[i].endswith('3') or Q[i].endswith('4') or
        Q[i].endswith('5') or Q[i].endswith('6') or
        Q[i].endswith('7') or Q[i].endswith('8') or
        Q[i].endswith('9')):
        Q[i]=Q[i][0:len(Q[i])-1]
D=''
for i in range(len(Q)):
    D+=Q[i]
pattern = re.compile(r"(?<=\d)(?=[a-zA-Z])|(?=\d)(?<=[a-zA-Z])")
result = re.sub(pattern, " ", D)
W=result.split(' ')
for i in range(len(W)):
    if W[i].endswith('i'):
        W[i]=W[i][0:len(W[i])-1]
for i in range(len(W)):
    if W[i].startswith('e'):
        W[i]=W[i][1:len(W[i])]
P=''
for i in W:
    if i=='':
        continue
    else:
        P+=i+', '
print('['+P[0:len(P)-2]+']')
```

Comment: Добавьте хотя бы свои попытки решить, а то вопрос могут закрыть

Comment: `([a-zA-Z]+){0,}[\s]{0,}([\d]+){0,}[\s]{0,}` разбивайте по группам, после выводите группы как надо, всего 2 группы будет и множество совпадений, уточню что python совершенно не знаю...

Comment: @FunnySad, не забывайте [голосовать за ответы или отмечать ответ как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"(?<=\d)(?=[a-zA-Z])|(?=\d)(?<=[a-zA-Z])")
input = "4 spami42e3 nani3e"
result = re.sub(pattern, " ", input)

print(result)
```

Ищем промежутки между буквой и цифрой или цифрой и буквой и заменяем их на пробел

Answer (score 1):

Вот так можно:

```
import re

def spl(a: str)-> str:
     return ' '.join([x for y in re.findall(r'\d+\s([\D]+)i(\d+)', a) for x in y])
```

Тест:

```
print(spl('4 spami42e3 nani3e'))
print(spl('10 mmmmmmasdwi432123432390e30 mamamsdsdlfokcmvndksolmcsqwerli40e'))
```

Соответственно:

> spam 42 nan 3
>
> mmmmmmasdw 432123432390 mamamsdsdlfokcmvndksolmcsqwerl 40

При этом такое решение раза в три быстрее, чем с `re.sub`.